# Mapping Entity in CouchDb Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, couchdb

I'm using couchDb in symfony 2.7.2.

I have several doubts.
Now I installed this [Bundle](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineCouchDBBundle)

And I create one entity for testing

```
<?php

namespace foo\GarageBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\CouchDB\Mapping\Annotations as CouchDB;

/**
 * @CouchDB\Document
 */
class Utente
{

    /** @CouchDB\Id */
    private $id;

    /** @CouchDB\Field(type="string") */
    private $nome;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nome
     *
     * @param string $nome
     * @return Utente
     */
    public function setNome($nome)
    {
        $this->nome = $nome;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nome
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNome()
    {
        return $this->nome;
    }
}
```

In my controller I added this Code

```
    $dm = $this->container->get('doctrine_couchdb.client.default_connection');
    $doc = $this->container->get('doctrine_couchdb.odm.default_document_manager');

    try{
        $dm->createDatabase($dm->getDatabase());
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        $msg = $e->getMessage();
    }

    $user = new Utente();
    $user->setNome('foo');
    $doc->persist($user);
    $doc->flush();
```

my config.yml is

```
doctrine_couch_db:
  client:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
        default:
            dbname: symfony2
  odm:
    default_document_manager: default
    document_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
```

With controller I created Database but I can't insert the new Document, I got this error

```
The class 'foo\GarageBundle\Document\Utente' was not found in the chain configured namespaces
```

And I don't understand why it is useful to use a bundle as what I am using ( I know it could be a stupid question ), and why I have to use `* @CouchDB\Document` instead of `@Document` inside my entity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems a problem related the namespace of the entity class.

> The automapping is registering [the CouchDocument subnamespace](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineCouchDBBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/DoctrineCouchDBExtension.php#L296) of
>   your bundle, not Document (which is auto-mapped by
>   DoctrineMongoDBBundle)

So use a different namespace for the `User` class and the other Counch you use, as follow:

```
namespace foo\GarageBundle\CouchDocument;
```

In particular:

```
<?php

namespace foo\GarageBundle\CouchDocument;

use Doctrine\ODM\CouchDB\Mapping\Annotations as CouchDB;

/**
 * @CouchDB\Document
 */
class Utente
{
```

Hope this help

See [this discussion on github](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineCouchDBBundle/issues/26).

Comment: Hi @monkeyUser you are welcome! I don't think is so trivial question: IMHO this requirements is not well documented.

Comment: Now it works, but I can't retrive the documents from my database .
`$dm = $this->container->get('doctrine_couchdb.odm.default_document_manager');
        $users = $dm->getRepository('myGarageBundle:Utente')->findAll();`
I have Three documents, but my array is empty.

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
 * @CouchDB\Document
 * @CouchDB\Index
 */
class Utente
{
```